# How to solve the differential equation $y'=y/(y+a)+b$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to determine the proportion of a quantity $y$ in a mixture of total quantity $y + a$. I know that the quantity $y$ evolves according to two components: one which is constant $b$ and another one which is proportional to the concentration of $y$ in $y + a$.

I get a weird differential equation where $y'$ depends both on $y$ but also on $1/y$, so it's not a differential equation per se.

Does anyone know how to solve this differential equation or have a trick to make it linear?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Since the right-hand side does not depend on $x$, you have a "separable equation".

[WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=y%27%28x%29%3Dy%28x%29%2F%28y%28x%29%2Ba%29%2Bb) seems to give explicit solutions in terms of the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) so you can probably follow the transformations to obtain this result formally.

As always with explicit solutions of ODEs, it is easier to check that it works than to guess it. Here, you can probably verify that looking for $y$ under the form
$$
y(t) = \alpha W [ e^{\beta t} ] + \gamma
$$
you can find coefficients $\alpha, \beta$ and $\gamma$ that give you the solution you are looking for, using e.g. that $z (1+W(z)) W'(z) = W(z)$. You should also take care of the singularities of these relations (see the Wikipedia page above).

Answer (score 0):

No need, this is seperable ODE:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y}{y+a}+b=\frac{y+by+ab}{y+a}$$

$$\Rightarrow \int \frac{y+a}{ab+(b+1)y}dy=\int dx$$

Comment: But solving the (implicit) equation for $y$ will probably also lead to the Lambert W function.

Comment: You can express $x$ by $y$, which is $x=x(y)$, and this is the implicit form.

Answer (score 0):

Different approach, same results. I tried getting the equation in the form $M(x,y)dx+N(x,y)dy=0$. That yields and M and N linear in x and y. Then a series of substitutions. When M and N are linear in x and y, sometimes the problem is easier changing variables to u=M(x,y), v=N(x,y) and rewriting as P(u,v)du+Q(u,v)dv=0

$y'=y/(y+a)+b\implies (y+a)y'=y+b(y+a)$

$ [(1+b)y+ab]dx-(y+a)dy=0 $

$u=y+a, du=dy$

$[u(1+b)-a ]dx-udu=0$

$v=u(1+b)-a. dv=du(1+b)$

$vdx-\frac{v+a}{1+b}\frac{dv}{1+b}$

$dx=\frac{(1+a/v)dv}{(1+b)^2}$

$x=\frac{1}{(1+b)^2}(v+a\ln{v})+C$ closely related to the Lambert W function.